# How validate this section of code?

Tags: php, html, validation

I have this code:

**HTML:**

```
<body class="adminInterface <?php echo $reqUriArr[count($reqUriArr)-2]."_".$reqUriArr[count($reqUriArr)-1]; ?>">
<script type="in/login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
```

And get these four errors ...

```
1.character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
2. an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter.
3.character data is not allowed here
4. there is no attribute "data-onAuth"
```

I code in two rows of four errors ... you can help me solve them please and tell me where they come from?

Thanks in advance!

**Info errors:**

1.

> This message may appear in several cases:
>
> You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape
>   it as "<" You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in
>   some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always
>   safe. Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a
>   previous tag.

2.

> Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the
>   attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value".

3.

> You have used character data somewhere it is not permitted to appear.
>   Mistakes that can cause this error include:
>
> putting text directly in the body of the document without wrapping it
>   in a container element (such as a
>
> aragraph
>
> ), or forgetting to
>   quote an attribute value (where characters such as "%" and "/" are
>   common, but cannot appear without surrounding quotes), or using
>   XHTML-style self-closing tags (such as ) in HTML 4.01 or
>   earlier. To fix, remove the extra slash ('/') character. For more
>   information about the reasons for this, see Empty elements in SGML,
>   HTML, XML, and XHTML.

4.

> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the
>   document type you are using does not support that attribute for this
>   element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict"
>   document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the
>   "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by
>   using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is
>   usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute,
>   (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both
>   allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this
>   attribute. If you received this error when using the  element
>   to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid
>   flash.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you elaborate your question.

Comment: Once I edit the post

Comment: You are trying to validate HTML, but you have also PHP in your code.

Comment: and is not possible to validate in this context?

Comment: If you process that code with PHP, it will return only HTML. This output you can validate.

Comment: and how can I do that? do not quite understand what you mean

Comment: When the php script is executed on the server, it produces output. Only this output is sent to the client/browser. So the client,browser,validation tool only "sees" the output and parses it as html (unless instructed otherwise). Call the php script from a browser and then use its _source code view_ to see what output the php script produced.